# Yosemite: Corrupt quick look images

Tags: quicklook

Ever since my transition to 10.10.5 Yosemite, quick look keeps corrupting the preview images every now and then. Sometimes is persists until reboot, other times it goes away after a while. The image files themselves are fine and open and display in any application.

Any ideas?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Why not update to El Capitan? That ought to fix this.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 How?

Comment: @JMY1000 Go to the Mac App Store and you should see somewhere it says "Update to El Capitan", then just download it and follow any on-screen instructions.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 Not what I meant :P I meant how would it fix the issue?

Comment: @JMY1000 Because it looks like a software issue and El Capitan corrected a lot of bugs in Yosemite. I would start there first, at least.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 Fair, but "Upgrade the OS" doesn't solve everything, and if they need/want to stay on 10.10, the question is still valid, as other 10.10 installs don't appear to have this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Create a guest Account**

and test if the problem still persists. To activate the guest account use the following steps:

- Open System Settings **Users & Groups**, click on the **lock** below to unlock it and type your password.
- On the left panel you see the **Guest Account**, activate it and log in and test.
- Deactivate it if you're done.

**Repair disk permissions with disk utility**

Sometimes files are corrupt and can be repair using the disk utility.

- Click on the Finder Desktop and then press the keys **Command + Shift + G**
- Insert the following path into the small window and hit **Enter** to open the location:

  `/Applications/Utilities/`
- Open Disk Utility and choose on the left panel your System drive.
- Click on **First Aid** (El Capitan) or below the buttons **check & repair** (Yosemite and below) to repair disk permissions. Restart and test if the problem still exists.

**Try to reset the quicklook cache**

Open Terminal (you find it in the utilities folder - see location above), and type the following commands:

```
qlmanage -r
qlmanage -r cache
```

*After this is done you need to move some files to your desktop.*

Open the following path location and move the files marked **bold** to your Desktop. Click on the Finder Desktop and press **Command + Shift + G** and insert the following path in the window:

```
~/Library/Preferences/
```

Move the following files to your Desktop:

**com.apple.QuickLookDaemon.plist**
**com.apple.quicklook.ui.helper.plist**
**com.apple.quicklookconfig.plist**

***Restart and Test***

**Check for Hardware Issues**

To see if there isn't a Hardware Problem restart your mac and press the **D** key during startup.

Comment: It remains a problem, and to add to it, the cached previews are actually fine. It is the full screen generated ones that are scrambled every now and then.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, because resetting the quicklook cache, does help, most of the time.

Comment: Sometimes the copy & text selection feature in Quicklook break the preview images. The defaults command works in Yosemite and earlier Versions. Unfortunately this feature was removed from El Capitan. So I don't write down im my Answer. You can try to disable it in Yosemite and try if works. But remember you loose the ability copy and select text. Here the command you should type in your Terminal: defaults write com.apple.finder QLEnableTextSelection -bool FALSE; killall Finder . To Enable replace FALSE with TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

This may help : http://encase-forensic-blog.guidancesoftware.com/2014/05/examination-of-mac-os-x-quick-look.html or https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1289781?tstart=0

You should be able to rebuild the so called ThumbnailCache on your mac.
This should work. hope this helps :)

Comment: Also try relaunching the finder in the force quit menu.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please refrain from posting link-only answers.  Links can change over time and questions and answers will lose their context.  You can see [answer] for info on how to provide good answers.  - From Review -

Comment: @Nate, sorry but relaunching the finder doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. I'll tell you if I find out any thing else on the issue.