# Preview.app corrupting images when rotating

Tags: macos, preview, quicklook

Preview.app is corrupting my images when I rotate them. Does anyone know why this might be? I've had issues with corrupt quicklook previews, but not this.

Before:
[image: picture before rotating]

After opening in Preview.app and rotating counter-clockwise once, then saving:

[image: corrupted picture after rotating in Preview.app]

Simultaneously, I also suffered the issues [described here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229417/yosemite-corrupt-quick-look-images), but I resolved that by clearing the caches as described.

Disk Utility reports my file system is healthy. I'm using a home-made fusion drive combining a 250 GB SSD and 750 GB HDD, not sure if that's relevant. Also, I don't think my memory is corrupt as I have no problems with system stability otherwise.

I tried some other pictures, some were garbled, some weren't:

This image rotated OK (only rotated shown):
[image: Rotated image remote control]

This image got garbled and mixed in parts of the previous image:

Original:
[image: sample 2 original image]

Rotated:
[image: Sample 2 rotated image]

Comment: Please edit your question and/or add tags to specify the version of macOS on your machine. Is this happening with _any_ file type you're working with (JPEG, GIF, PDF, PNG) or one specific file type? I don't think the HD format, (homegrown or otherwise,) has any bearing on this problem.

Comment: So it only happens after you save it?

Comment: @IconDaemon 1) I have yosemite, so I tagged my question with 'yosemite'. Are there other applicable tags I missed? 2) Some JPEG files have this, others don't. I do think it's related to memory as images are mingled after rotating (see new examples)

Comment: @jmh Yes, the image looks OK in Preview, then when I save it it appears garbled in Quicklook, and when I re-open with Preview it's still garbled.

Comment: I just tried rotating a single page in a large PDF. I saved as a new file name. When I open the new file it looks fine.  I'm baffled.

Comment: Memory (RAM) and disk (storage) are two different things.

Comment: Thanks @IconDaemon, I'm aware of this, I've updated my question to more clearly distinguish these.